# Using expect to login to amazon server with .PEM file

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, expect, pem

I need to do the following:

- Log into my amazon server
- Change to a specific directory and run a script
- The script executes an `svn up`, I need to be able to pass my username and password to this script.

I've read I might be able to do this with expect? Can I do the login via a shell script and then invoke expect to run the custom script?

Basically, I'm just looking for a good way to do this and would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: This is possible with `expect`, as well as other tools like `fabric`, which is a python module. Expect manual: http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/, Python fabric doc: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.2/index.html

Comment: Thanks - A lot easier than i thought.  Here's the code if it's useful to anyone.  By running ssh in verbose i can be sure that the connection is help open long enough for the script to run.

`#!/usr/bin/expect 
set timeout -1
spawn ssh -vi key.pem user@server.com "cd /to/my/script && run deploy"
expect "username:"
send "user\r"
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
expect "Exit status"
`

Comment: What I'd normally do would be to spawn a shell and then do all the magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh to pass a shell commands to be run on remote Instance.

For example, here's how I check logs on multiple Servers:

```
#!/bin/bash
nas_servers=(
  "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
  "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
  "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
  "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
)

for s in "${nas_servers[@]}"
do
  echo "Cheking $s:"
  ret=$(ssh -i ~/pem/Key.pem "user@$s" bash << 'EOF'
  files=/var/log/syslog*
  for f in $files
  do
if [[ ${f##*.} = 'gz' ]]; then
  cmd=zcat
else
  cmd=cat
fi
$cmd $f | egrep -wi 'error|warn|crit|fail'
  done
EOF
)
  if [[ -z $ret ]]; then
echo "No errors found."
  else
echo "$ret"
  fi
done
```